# Multiple triggers for an Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

We have an Azure Function that has an event hub trigger. Is it possible to have a trigger on more than one event hub for the same Azure Function?

Comment: I believe yes, but you would have to set them up manually, not through the wizard, just edit the configuration file

Comment: @4c74356b41 I tried modifying the bindings in function.json and it didn't seem to work. :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, this is not a supported scenario at the moment.

> From comments (Ling Toh Jan 18 '17 at 18:23):
>   There are no plans to support multiple triggers per Function. You will have to create a Function for each EventHub. If there is common code that may be shared between Functions, you may move them to a helper method that can be called from each Function.

Comment: Is this something that will be supported in the future?

Comment: There are no plans to support multiple triggers per Function.  You will have to create a Function for each EventHub.  If there is common code that may be shared between Functions, you may move them to a helper method that can be called from each Function.

Answer (score 2):

From  [Github: Any workarounds for adding multiple triggers? #1544](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1544#issuecomment-304994898)

> If you want to have your same function code run for blobs in either
> account A or account B, the easiest thing to do this is to create
> **multiple function.json files** for each function but have them share the
> same code by pointing to the same script file. There's more info [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Precompiled-functions).