# Control on trigger blob App Function Azure

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-functions

I have created an App Function with Blob Trigger on Azure. I want to know if it's possible to launch the trigger IF the trigger hasn't been launch during 24 hours. I know that it's an option to launch the trigger each X hours but is there an option to launch it if it's not launched during 24 hours. FYI, The trigger is launched if there is an update on a file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for multiple triggers, you can either have blob trigger or timer trigger for the moment according to this :

[Multiple triggers for an Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695474/multiple-triggers-for-an-azure-function)